# Calling a jquery function after multiple get request is completed

Tags: php, jquery

alright so on my site my home page on load create 4 carousels by using the .get method. I am wondering how one might call a js function after every carousel has been successfully loaded. Sometimes there are 3 to 4 sometimes there aren't any carousels. Is their anyway of tracking if i am requesting anything using get?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: If you are sending them all off at the same time, you can use ajaxComplete.

Comment: i do send them in at the same time but they end at different intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery recently introduced the [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object and made every ajax call return an [jqxhr](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object that works as a [promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A). All this means you can get out of the callback pyramid of madness situations with a syntax like this:

```
$.when(
    $.get('http://example.com'),
    $.get('http://example.com'),
    $.get('http://example.com')
).done(function(resp1, resp2, resp3){
    console.log(resp1, resp2, resp3);
    alert('all done \o/');
});
```

*Note*: the `done` function(s) will be called only when all previous promise returns successfully. For a callback that runs no mater what use [always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/). For catching only errors there's [fail](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/).